# Python Curses windows are not shown properly every time I run the program

Tags: python, python-3.x, ncurses, python-curses

I have this wierd problem with ncurses in Python 3.4 I am trying to make some windows as layout for my application and code looks like this:

```
import curses
import time
class Presentator():
    def __init__(self, device_db, address_db):
        self.curses_windows = {}
    def update_all_windows(self):
        for wins in self.curses_windows.values():
            wins.noutrefresh()
        curses.doupdate()

    def update_all_windows(self):
        for wins in self.curses_windows.values():
            wins.noutrefresh()
        curses.doupdate()

    def create_windows(self):
        max_height = curses.LINES - 5
        max_width = curses.COLS - 5
        self.curses_windows["border"] = curses.newwin(max_height, max_width, 0, 0)
        self.curses_windows["border"].border()
        self.curses_windows["title"] = curses.newwin(3, max_width, 0, 0)
        self.curses_windows["title"].border()
        title_msg = "IP MONITORING"
        self.curses_windows["title"].addstr(1, max_width // 2 - len(title_msg), title_msg)


    def print_results(self, stdscr):
        self.create_windows()
        while True:
            self.update_all_windows()
            time.sleep(5)


    def start_ui(self):
        curses.wrapper(self.print_results)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Presentator()
    p.start_ui()
```

Two out of 5 times I run the program, two windows with borders are shown, with title message IP-MONITORING inside. This is correct however, the rest 3 cases only the border of `self.curses_windows["border"]` window is shown and nothing else. Am I doing something wrong with refreshing? Why is the result unpredictable?

Thanks for help.

Comment: probably because the list of windows is unordered (the usual case with associative arrays)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a non-numeric array index, that's actually an associative array (also referred to in python as a dictionary), and the iteration

```
for wins in self.curses_windows.values():
```

does not have a predefined order.  So sometimes one window will be last to be refreshed, sometimes another.  If you write the border last, it wipes out the "contents".